# Currency Parsing in Java

Tags: java, regex, currency, number-formatting

I'm trying to parse a html tag so far I got the text which can be as follows:

"Guide Price £50,000"

or

"£50,000"

or even

"£50,000 - £55,000"

In the third case to make things simpler all I need is the first price listed.

My question is how can I convert the following numbers into an int or double, preferably an int as the numbers are quite large.  Would number formatter do this or would I need a regex expression especially if some text trails the tag block.

**Example after what I got so far**

```
String priceNumber = url.select("span.price").text();  //using JSoup Libary
String priceNumber = priceNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d.])
```

This removes everything which is not a digit I think.
What if the example has 2 numbers in it how do I get the first?

Comment: Can you provide a Code Example of what you have right now?

Comment: Also Strings are immutable so my example is not so good what I need is an exmaple of string buffer to select the first number minus the commas, dots and currency sign and return it as an integer

Comment: You don't need a StringBuffer (or a StringBuilder, which should have been your first choice if you needed such a thing).  Just assign the value returned by `replaceAll()` to a string variable like you're doing now.  That part of your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with `Matcher.find` to search for occurrences, then remove the commas and try to parse.  Here's the decimal case:

```
String input = "£50,000 - £55,000";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\d,\\.]+");
Matcher finder = regex.matcher(input);
if( finder.find() ) { // or while() if you want to process each
  try {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(finder.group(0).replaceAll(",", ""));
    // do something with value
  } catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
    // handle unparseable
  }
}
```

Comment: I'my stuck on the bus @Jake looks promising and I will attempt to do a price range either 500 or 50,000 or 50,000,000

Answer (score 0):

Youu can convert any `String` to a `int` or `double` with `Integer.parseInt(\\String you want to convert)` or `Double.parseDouble(\\String you want to convert)` respectively.

In your first and second case this would get you `50000`.
In the third cae you need to split the string into 2 first and then repeat the trick.

Your title is a bit misleading as you are not asking on how to convert from pound to lets say euro.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to remove the unimportant characters and then parse the result as a double.  You can then truncate to int if you only care about dollar values.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
format.parse(priceNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]*([\\d,]*).*", "$1")).doubleValue()
```

The first part of the replace pattern `[^\\d]` matches and throws away leading characters, the second part `([\\d,])` saves the next series of digits and commas, then the third part `.*` throws away the rest of the input.

Then the whole input is replaced with the contents of the first saved match (the second part of the replace pattern).

Then you use the NumberFormat class to parse the number (you could use `Double.parseDouble()` if it weren't for the comma)

Answer (score 0):

This will work I think!

```
    String string = "This is £50,000 pounds, this is £5.00 pounds.";
    String newString = string;

    while (string.contains("£")) {

        if (string.indexOf("£") != -1) {
            // it contains £
            string = string.substring(string.indexOf("£"));
            newString = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(" "));

            string = string.replaceFirst(newString, "");

            newString = newString.replaceAll("£", "");
            newString = newString.replaceAll(",", "");

            double money = Double.parseDouble(newString);

            System.out.println(money);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out (for all the cases),

```
String priceNumber = "£500001   wcjnwknv122333- £55,000";
String regex = "£(\\d+,?\\d+)\\D?";

Pattern p =Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(priceNumber);
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex  :

```
   ((\$|£)\d+\s|(\$|£)\d+-(\$|£)\d+\s)
```